# Is there a possibility to show an icon for symbolic link resource in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, symlink, indicator

I work with Linux and use symbolic links (symlinks) in my project to share common files in different places. I also use subversive as team provider plugin.

For symlinked folders Eclipse, or better Subclipse, shows an arrow overlay on the file icon in the project explorer. But for symlinked files this little arrow is not shown. So it is impossible to tell if the file is symlinked as it looks like a normal file.

Is there an option or plugin that makes it possible to have a visual indicator for if it is a regular file or a symlink?

Answer (score 0):

The next version of Eclipse, i.e. 4.3, will include a symlink decoration.